# How do I remove a period from a JSON key?

Tags: json, key

I have a JSON payload that looks like this:

```
{
"Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
    "1. From_Currency Code": "BTC",
    "2. From_Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
    "3. To_Currency Code": "CNY",
    "4. To_Currency Name": "Chinese Yuan",
    "5. Exchange Rate": "252335.42242500",
    "6. Last Refreshed": "2021-06-14 06:05:06",
    "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
    "8. Bid Price": "252335.35845800",
    "9. Ask Price": "252335.42242500"
}
```

}

I would like to remove all the numberings from the Key Value pairs, so it should end up looking like this

```
{
"Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
    "From_Currency Code": "BTC",
    "From_Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
    "To_Currency Code": "CNY",
    "To_Currency Name": "Chinese Yuan",
    "Exchange Rate": "252335.42242500",
    "Last Refreshed": "2021-06-14 06:05:06",
    "Time Zone": "UTC",
    "Bid Price": "252335.35845800",
    "Ask Price": "252335.42242500"
}
```

}

I really appreciate any help on achieving this? Thank you.

Comment: In what language? If its plain json then copy it on notepad++ and use regex find and replace to remove `\d\. ` with empty string

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I need to do this via Javascript.

Comment: Okay @natoahs check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach would be simple. We take each key of json object and we replace its digit part with empty string then copy the data of old key to new key and delete the old key.

```js
const json=`{
  "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
    "1. From_Currency Code": "BTC",
    "2. From_Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
    "3. To_Currency Code": "CNY",
    "4. To_Currency Name": "Chinese Yuan",
    "5. Exchange Rate": "252335.42242500",
    "6. Last Refreshed": "2021-06-14 06:05:06",
    "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
    "8. Bid Price": "252335.35845800",
    "9. Ask Price": "252335.42242500"
  }
}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
const index = 'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate';

Object.keys(obj[index]).forEach(key => {
   var newKey = key.replace(/\d+\. /g, '');
   obj[index][newKey] = obj[index][key];
   delete obj[index][key];
});

console.log(obj);
```